# What is the plurality naming "problem" in context of Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What do the people mean when talking of the plurality naming "problem" in context of Entity Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.cnblogs.com/zjz008/archive/2010/06/03/1750442.html (re: Entity Framework 4.0 Features)...

> **Plurality Naming**
>
> One of the big complaints in the first
>   version of the Entity Framework was
>   how naming conventions were applied to
>   EDM objects such as entities and
>   navigation properties when using the
>   model wizards.
>
> The first version of
>   the Entity Framework gave the Entity
>   Name and the Entity Set Name the same
>   name. There was no attempt to
>   singularize or pluralize names when
>   generating a model from a database.
>   The problem is that this caused some
>   confusion when referencing the
>   database table or EntityType in code.
>   For example, if your database has a
>   table called Employees, then you will
>   also get an EntityType called
>   Employees as well. This causes
>   confusion about whether you are
>   referencing the table or the
>   EntityType, such as in the code
>   fragment below.
>
> `Customers customer = new Customers();`
>
> Luckily, this issue
>   has been addressed. The model wizards,
>   both the Entity Data Model and Update
>   Model Wizards, now provide the option
>   of using singular or plural forms of
>   names for entities, entity sets, and
>   navigation properties.
>
> The goal of
>   this change was to make the
>   application code much easier to read
>   and avoid a lot of the confusion
>   between object names.

Answer (score 2):

It revolves around the fact that database objects named in certain ways will lead to either incorrect pluralization or singularization.  A good example of this is illustrated by this [Microsoft Connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/539109/entity-framework-pluralization-incorrect-for-word-status).

In this example, database objects end in "Status" are incorrectly singularized as "Statu", instead of being treated as a singularization that would be pluralized as "Statuses".

It is annoying, but I wouldn't consider it to be widespread enough to deter a person from using EF.